# Android: Save a photo into photo gallery

Tags: android, genymotion

I went onto Facebook in my Genymotion emulator and saved down a photo.

It went into my photo gallery but I cannot find it in my Android Device Monitor.

[image: facebook pic]

Where is it saved in my emulator?

My emulator:

[image: genymotion]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via Android Device Monitor you can find your image in this path:

```
/mnt/shell/emulated/0/DCIM/Facebook/FB_IMG_1446233000157.jpg
```

As you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I clicked on that folder but there was nothing there... Thats the legacy folder in the screenshot right?

Comment: No, in your the screenshot you have opened `/storage/emulated/legacy/`. You need to open the path `/mnt/shell/emulated/0/`. I just updated the answer adding a screenshot, please take a look.